# Easy to implement .net library for geocoding using a free service?

Tags: .net, geocoding

I need to geocode adresses (get lat/long from addresses) using in .Net, to store in the database.

What is the library/project to look into, to get that done?

After a search here, on google and [codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=GeoCoding), I have found there to be a few options, that seem like they will do what I ask for... But some of them could be crap and a waste of time - and some might just be stellar.

Which one is the one to go for? Have you used any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Google Maps API or Microsoft MapPoint API this is very easy to do. It depends a lot on your usage requirements, ie how many geocodes do you plan on doing on an ongoing basis.

Comment: Very few - like initially 3-400 and then maybe 20 a week - so very little.

Comment: I think Google Maps terms of use deny storing resolved lat/long in a database though.

Comment: I don't think this is correct regarding Google Maps and storing geocodes. I have done a lot of work with Google Maps and my experience with them is they encourage storing lat/long to reduce load on their servers. They don't encourage wholesale storage of their data in your database however, for example using Google Base they wouldn't want you to do a complete product dump.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [GeoCoding.Net](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net) - generic geocoding API for Google, Yahoo, and Bing

Answer (score 1):

We use [geoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) for our geocoding needs.   Just connect, send your query, and it will return XML or JSON (in some cases).
[Here is an article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/GeoNames-WCFClient.aspx) on how to wire it up with WCF.